# What path finding algorithm is the best one for my sitatuion?

Tags: algorithm

Lets say I have 2000 nodes, and out of those 2000, 100 of them are acceptable paths to take, but I want to take the shortest path of the 100 nodes, which algorithm is the best for this and why?

(Also I haven't really dove into path finding that much so I don't know much terminology yet.)

Comment: You mean ["Travelling Salesperson Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe i'm wrong

Comment: Then explain better what you mean. You want to visit all the 100 nodes? or you can't visit the other 1900? If it's the latter, just remove them from the graph with their edges. What does it mean for a node to be an "acceptable path"? A node isn't a path.

Comment: I'm sorry I reread what I posted and I left the most important part out.. I want to find the shortest path out of the 100 possible goals.

Comment: Still unclear. Do you mean shortest path to any one of the 100 nodes from some other given node? i.e. shortest path to everywhere terminating when one of the 100 is hit? Also, are the edge weights all positive? 
(PS update the question please so others don't need to read comments)

Comment: Do you mean that you have a starting node, and a 'moat' of 100 nodes around the starting node, with a goal of finding the shortest path across the moat?

Comment: Taking into account that you aren't experienced in pathfinding, still this is unclear: "I have 2000 nodes, and out of those 2000, 100 of them are acceptable paths to take" - a *node* and a *path* are different! Maybe draw us a diagram of a smaller case where, say, you have **20** nodes and **3** are "acceptable paths to take" ?

Comment: Apparently, OP has one starting node, and 100 possible end nodes, and the goal is to find the shortest path from the start node to any one of the end nodes. If the edges all have the same weight (i.e. an unweighted graph), then the answer to the question is a simple BFS. On the other hand, if the edges are weighted, then the answer is Dijkstra's algorithm (with early termination).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 100 of them are acceptable paths? If it gives you the paths already, and since 100 is a fairly small number, I would perform complete search towards the given paths. If you mean ignoring either nodes/edges, then choose Dijkstra's Algorithm in order to find your path in $\mathcal{O}(V + E\log V)$.